# Jquery Ajax multi user request

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am very new into ajax and i am having a strange problem, I have created an asp.net website that have a web service within the project I am calling this web service by following ajax code:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: pageUrl + "/PassData",
    data: JSON.stringify({ aos_code: code }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccessCall
});
```

the c# code is not very complicated, basically it will get the code and call the stored procedure and return some value:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string[] PassData(string aos_code)
{
    // calling the database and returning some data
    return data;
}
```

And it works fine; the problem is that if two different users accessing the application in the two different computers and let say they clicking a button at the same time to call the server side function via Ajax, it will return the “500 internal server error”.

I am not sure how exactly Ajax work, is request are belong to same session or all user requesting a single function?
Hope it makes sense, and I would really do appreciate for the clarification and help.

Regards,

Comment: I'm afraid that make no sense. Could you please paste your c# code?

Comment: It might be a threading problem, but you will need to post the C# code, as that is what is generating the 500 error.

Comment: Check this http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm

Comment: Thanks for all the helps, I have explain the c# code,  also should mention that it’s not giving me error every time, it happen sometime, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 indicates that something went wrong on the server side.  Check your console (firebug or similar) to see what exactly happened and try to fix it.  Ajax has nothing to do with it, it is simply as if two users visited the same page at the same time.